# How can I create a Dynamodb table with same definition in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have some 200 tables in Singapore region and I want all the tables in my Oregon region.
I want only tables same as created in Singapore.

with:

```
Partition key
Sort Key
Read capacity
Write capacity
GSI
LSI
```

is there any way to do it?
instead of doing it manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the 200 tables in the first place? Manually as well? If not, use the same script.

I am not aware of any existing DB export tool.

You could create a script though that fetches the vital information from each table and creates it again using the CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/

Alternatively: If groups of these databases are similarly structured, you could try writing a cloudformation template per group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ListTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html) and  [Describe Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) call to query all your tables in the Singapore region.  You can then use the create table api in the new region.